# Store 'time' in firebase each time user clicks a button

Tags: javascript, angularjs, firebase

I have a todo list with a 'Done' button. I want to store the time in firebase each time the user clicks the button. The button gets enabled after a while and when the user clicks the button again i want to store the time again and not overwrite the existing time. In my code, the time gets overwritten.

index.html

```
<ion-list class = "list">
    <ion-item class = "has-header" ng-repeat="todo in data.todos" class = "item" ng-class="{purchased: todos.status == 'purchased'}">
     {{todo.title}}
      <button  ng-disabled="todo.stopSpam" ng-click="doneItem(todo)">Done
      </button>
```

app.js

```
$scope.doneItem = function(todo) {

  todo.stopSpam = true; 
  todo.timestamp = Date();

  $interval(callAtInterval, 30000);

  function callAtInterval(){
    todo.stopSpam = false;  
  }

};
```

Answer (score 1):

To avoid overwriting existing data, your code should create new child nodes for each time you want to store data within that node.

Given ref is your root ref

```
var timestampsRef = ref.child("timestamps");
var newTimestampRef = timestampsRef.push();

newTimestampRef.set({
    stamp: "a timestamp"
});
```

Calling it each time the user presses the button will create a distinct node name and then add the time stamp as a child to each one.

```
  "timestamps": {
    "-QIUEiijasdj923498": {
      "stamp": "a timestamp"
    },
    "-Qnbnajsd093409koi": {
      "stamp": "a timestamp"
    }
```